# How to get file sharing (/mnt/c) to work for wsl linux VM running on Window-11

Tags: linux, windows, ubuntu, virtual-machine

I have successfully got a Linux VM working on my Windows-11. However when I start either Ubuntu or Debian session I get the following error:
WSL2-Linux-Kernel:linux-msft-wsl

and once logger on /mnt/c director is there but does not cd by C: drive. No surprise given the error on start-up.

Have searched for this and got a confusing variety of answers. One says the wsl 'kernel' is wrong, but I don't know how to change it or what a good one is. A real non-expert here.

Others have a confusing variety of confusing prescriptions.

I'd like a clear-cut procedure (or pointer to one that's 'out-there').

Comment: Have you tried from Linux    SMB://ipofwindows/drive  and authenticate?

Comment: is `WSL2-Linux-Kernel:linux-msft-wsl` the full extent of the error? ... what does *"does not cd by C: drive"* actually mean?